# Can't figure out the correct wheelset size for my Raleigh Rush Hour to replace the stock wheelset

Tags: frames, wheels

I'm trying to order a new wheelset for my Raleigh Rush Hour.  The problem being that my bike is at a friends right now and it might stay there for a bit,  I can't remember what frame size I have and I was wondering if the Rush Hour's wheelset changed size based on frame size or if they all just had the same wheelset.  If all of the frame sizes roll with the same size wheelset then I can order based on the stock wheelset.  Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 3):

It's rare for a manufacturer to have different wheel sizes for the same model, but it does happen sometimes. Fortunately, it's easy to check the wheel size, it's always printed or embossed somewhere on the tires. Yours will probably say 700c or 622mm or 28 inch - these are all equivalent.

One other thing you'll have to consider is the [rear dropout spacing](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html). If you can't find the manufacturer specs, you'll have to measure it. Most road bikes use 130 mm, and most track bikes use 120 mm, I have no idea what yours is. (The front dropouts are almost certainly 100 mm).

Comment: And yes, I know that 28" != 622 mm. In this case, 28" is just a marketing name, the actual number has only a loose connection to reality.

Answer (score 2):

Wheel size will remain the same, which is 700c, The different sizes of frames will only effect the overall geometry. So yes, you'll be fine getting a replacement of the same stock size.